# Is it possible to attach a test case from a test plan to a pipeline release test run result? Azure DevOps API V6.0

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to meet a requirement for work and am not sure if its a pipeline set up issue or what.

Essentially we have a pipeline release set up in Azure DevOps that runs our automated tests from a build that is connected to our automated project repo.

Once a run is done we get passed and failed test results. These automated test cases are associated with manual test cases written and stored in a test plan. When I view the failed test results programmatically I want to be able to view the related test plan id, suite Id, and test case ID in the data. How can this be achieved?

The only associated data I get is a test case reference id, but the only API I found to use this with was
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/testresults/result%20meta%20data?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
However, this only gives me the name of tests .dll and some other info not useful for my goal.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I view the failed test results programmatically I want to be able to view the related test plan id, suite Id, and test case ID in the data. How can this be achieved?

You could try this Rest API : [Results - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results/{testCaseResultId}?api-version=6.0
```

You could get the RunId and ResultId when you open the Test Case Result.

[image]

Tested with the automated tests, I could get the Test Case ID, Test Suite and Test Plan ID.

Here the Result sample:

[image]

Comment: Hey, happy Friday Kevin thank you for the response. When I try the above I only get the name of the test method but no id. I think I may end up going a different route with how our tests are run in Azure and run them directly from a test plan through the pipeline. I believe when ran from there I would have full access to the test data.

Comment: @MarkWhite. I run the [automated tests from the test plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops). Then I could get the information above.  Could you please share your test method? Is it same as mine?

Comment: Hi @MarkWhite. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if it could work in your side.

Comment: Hello Kevin, my apologies. As you stated above "I run the automated tests from the test plan", that is not how I am currently set up. I am in the process this week or next to test running our automation from a test plan to see if that will produce the results I am looking for. I will mark your answer as the solution as it has led me in the right direction. I appreciate you following up! Have a great day!